# Direct X Vertex Coloring

Tags: c++, directx, vertex, color

So I've been messing around with directx 9 for the past few days, and I recently bump in a simple problem of vertex coloring. Can someone here with directx9 expirience solve this problem? I would appreciate that. I incuded a video to lay out this unpopular problem.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhU1vuHKAQU&feature=plcp